# New project - JSF vs JSP

Tags: jsp, jsf

Hi I'm looking for someone to build a new classified site using Java.  My understanding is JSF is the latest framework (ie newer than JSP).  But it appears developers who are versed with JSF are far and in between compared to JSP.  While I understand that for existing setup that was built using JSP it makes sense to continue doing so but if this is a brand new project, is there any reason to avoid JSF?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/2095397/1065197

Answer (score 0):

Using the JSF , you get automatic binding your data to visual components , including mapping, validation of input data and save state between requests. Using JSP - all you have to implement it manually. JSF and also supports Ajax interaction with the server .

If you are developing an application that requires a standard behavior, such as data entry, editing and display - that JSF will suit you.
If you need an online application with fast response, navigation within a page on the client side ,such as gmail or twitter - you can spend a lot of time translating the client-side logic components in the JSF. In this case, you better use the JSP , as a source of data and JavaScript library to display data.

Therefore, JSF is not suitable for all types of projects, so that those who use JSP, not moving to "JSF"

Recommend the use of an intermediate option that gives freedom and developers on the client side and on the server without a hard peg to the model , for example "Apache Wicket"

Comment: Sorry when you said "you can spend a lot of time translating the client-side logic components in the JSF. In this case, you better use the JSF", you meant to say "...In this case, you better use the JSP", right?

Comment: Yes, I made a mistake in the response. In this case it is better to use JSP

Comment: @jDimitry I'm now experimenting with Grails.  Any opinions of that compared to JSP?  Again it appears to be a lot more difficult to find Grails developers than JSP developers (looking at job sites there are more JSP tags) but think it's also improved over pure JSP?  What do you think?